# Azure AppInsights query union

Tags: azure, kql

I've been writing some queries against AppInsights and noticed that in my data there's 2 ways of determining if a username exists against the telemetry.

```
customEvents 
 | where tostring(parse_json(tostring(customDimensions)).username) != '' or tostring(parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.Properties)).username) != ''
 | project
Username = tostring(parse_json(tostring(customDimensions)).username),
timestamp = timestamp
| distinct Username, bin(timestamp, 1d) 
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1d) 
| render timechart
```

Bit stuck, notice in the first where there's 2 ways of determing whether a record is valid, how do I change the projection to then say "if username is here, take it from here, else check in customDimensions.Properties

I assume we need a union from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [`coalesce()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction):

```
datatable(customDimensions: string)
[
    '{"username": "user1"}',
    '{"Properties": {"username": "user2"}}'
]
| where customDimensions has 'username'
| extend cd = parse_json(customDimensions)
| project UserName = tostring(coalesce(cd.username, cd.Properties.username))
| where isnotempty(UserName)
```

| Username |
| --- |
| user1 |
| user2 |